# Why won't wp_list_pages work in functions.php?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the following code to add a submenu that only displays the current top level parent and any children pages if within their parent. It works when used directly in sidebar.php but when I wrap it in a function and place it in functions.php, it only shows all of my top level menu items and not the active parent. How can I get it to work?

**Works in the sidebar:**

```
<?php
$child_of_value = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );
    $depth_value = ( $post->post_parent ? 2 : 1 );
        $wp_list_pages_args = array( 
            'child_of' => $child_of_value,
            'depth' => $depth_value,
            'title_li' => '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->post_parent).'">'.get_the_title($post->post_parent).'</a>'
        );
    wp_list_pages( $wp_list_pages_args );
?>
```

**Doesn't work in functions.php**

```
function page_submenu() {   
    $child_of_value = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );
    $depth_value = ( $post->post_parent ? 2 : 1 );
        $wp_list_pages_args = array( 
            'child_of' => $child_of_value,
            'depth' => $depth_value,
            'title_li' => '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->post_parent).'">'.get_the_title($post->post_parent).'</a>'
        );
    wp_list_pages( $wp_list_pages_args );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `global $post;` to the function. It works!